# How to format form?

Tags: macros, article, msword, word-to-latex

Consider this word document, like:
[image: Image of word document]

The expectation is to fill out this word document. When I try to format this document into
LaTeX format, it becomes extremely difficult, i.e., how to do it so that it fits into the framework(i.e., no `\textbf\underline` that kind of stuff hanging around)? Especially consider several requirements:

- I should be able to type directly after, or create a new paragraph and let them hold a new line individually.
- I should be able to use `\section`, `\subsection` all that kind of stuff in the content that I filled. For example, the challenge description part is really long that it would take several pages with sections and subsections.

However, I am not obliged to stick with this format. I have the freedom to choose whatever format I wish, but I don't know if there is a better alternative way to format that kind of key, value pairs.

Now comes the question

- Would you suggest I use `\section` or `\paragraph` for those? If so, how could I handle both cases, typing directly after the section header in the same line and creating a new paragraph after it?
- Would you suggest creating a new `\description` environment and using `enumitem` to suppress the left margin? If so, would you say this is somehow an unnatural way to do things in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I do not see any challenge in that format, but It is unclear what you are doing and therefore what are your real issues. Please to ask only for a concrete issue per question, showing a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how you are trying to solve the  issue, plus a screenshot of the result. Then explain clearly what is wrong in that output, and how it should be exactly so that anyone can edit the MWE and make the necessary changes to reach your goal.

Comment: It's not about I can't format it in this way. It's instead, what is the TeX way to do the thing?  I could definitely use any methods to make the thing work and looks like this Word document, but wouldn't that break the philosophy of the separation between the style and the content?